PowerApps: Update empty field with Patch function creates a new record
I'm trying to update a "DateFormat" field in an "Employee" Sharepoint list.
The value get selected via a dropdown box (defaulted to current settings) and is saved via Patch function when clicking the "Save" button.
When the current "DateFormat" value is empty, the Patch function will create a new record instead of updating the current one.
Patch(Employees, LookUp(Employees, employeeEMail=User().Email),
 {employeePreferredDateFormat:drpEmployeeDateFormat.Selected.Value});

Additionally the new record created contains the new DateFormat value but in the wrong column.
What am I doing wrong?
I expected the Patch function to Update the record corresponding to the LookUp value.
At least if it didn't find the record, I would have expected an error instead of a new record.

Hi Nicolas can you please share the backend names of your columns? The one in which value is expected and another where value is being pushed.
